# What is the Regex For the following pattern

Tags: c#, regex

requrements:

1)So basically I need that the words in backticks have to be [A-Za-z0-9]+

2) the number of words in back ticks is unknown but MUST be in sequence and seperated by a comma

3) after 'FROM' the string must be [A-Za-z0-9]+

this is what I have so far:

```
   String command = "SHOW TABLE COLUMNS `abcdf123`,`abcdf123`,`abcdf123` FROM ABCDF123";
   Match CMD = Regex.Match(command, @"SHOW(\s+)TABLE(\s+)COLUMNS(\s+)(a sequence of words enclosed in backticks seperated by a coma)(\s+)FROM(\s+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (CMD.Success)
            return true;
       else
        return false;
```

any Ideas would be greatly apreciated I am still new to Regex

Comment: Do you want to capture some part of the string or you want only a check?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I need a check and i will capture the string using the regex Groups property in my case would be CMD.Groups[4].Value ... so I need both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
\ASHOW TABLE COLUMNS (?:`(?<column_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`,?)+ FROM (?<table_name>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\z
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yf7t_iGyfiZ79Wzq)

Fails if a non alphanumeric character exists between backtick pairs.

### Test 1

All alphanumeric. Expected to pass.

```
SHOW TABLE COLUMNS `abcdf123`,`abcdf123`,`abcdf123` FROM ABCDF123
```

**MATCHED**

### Test 2

Single non-alphanumeric character between one backtick pair. Expected to fail.

```
SHOW TABLE COLUMNS `abcdf123`,`abcdf123*`,`abcdf123` FROM ABCDF123
```

**NO MATCH**

### Test 3

Single non-alphanumeric character in table name. Expected to fail.

```
SHOW TABLE COLUMNS `abcdf123`,`abcdf123`,`abcdf123` FROM ABCDF123*
```

**NO MATCH**

Comment: You don't need to use a lazy quantifier here, you can remove the `?`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are right. ill take it out. Artifact from initial experimentation.

Comment: Awesome...Thx It works.... let me vigourisly test it Before I mark you correct. thanks again

Comment: @FabioDelarias I've left single spaces in as the string to defined in your code is literal. You database may allow any whitespace so you may want to modify the pattern. I've also updated the pattern with a 'start of string' anchor.

Comment: ok slight problem you match is spot on but When I try to retrieve the string using the group property of regex match I Only see that the last string enclosed in back-ticks is captured but i need to capture the entire sequence of strings enclosed in back-ticks. the match works though... I need to capture the whole sequence of back-tick strings

Comment: @FabioDelarias how are you accessing the group? It should be `match.Group[1].Captures`

Comment: @FabioDelarias updated with named groups for clarity. The groups `column_name` and `table_name` should now give your the data you want.

Comment: @Gusdor Yes that is correct But I had to change it two **SHOW TABLE COLUMNS ((`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`,?)+) FROM [a-zA-Z0-9]+** so As to capture whole sequence and not just last string enclosed in back-ticks but all strings enclosed in back-ticks... but its looking good so far am just doing more testing.

Comment: @FabioDelarias I'll tell you what i keep telling my boss: "Wasn't in requirements so I didn't do it." :P Would `string.Join` have helped you through that one?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
SHOW(\s+)TABLE(\s+)COLUMNS(\s+)(\`[\w\d]*?\`\,?)+FROM(\s+)([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: `\w` includes `\d`, and also `_` that is not wanted, and this regex matches zero length column name.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for matching your command string is:

```
^[^`]*?`([^`]+)`+[\s\S]*?FROM\s+([a-zA-Z\d]+)[\s\S]*$


`([^`]+)` - will match data between backticks and the matching continues until
FROM is encountered.

([a-zA-Z\d]+)  - will match text after FROM clause (expecting that there is 
atlest one space after FROM)
```

The text matched in backticks can be obtained by using \1 (group 1 matching) and the text after FROM clause can be obtained by using \2 (group 2 matching).